# Columns in table not getting inserted according to json object

Tags: angularjs

I'm iterating over an array and values for Height and Sex are getting interchanged when it is displayed in the table

View:

```
<table  class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr><th ng-repeat="instanceItem in instancesData.Attributes track by $index" >{{instanceItem.Name}}</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in instancesData.Values track by $index">
        <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in row">{{value}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.instancesData = {
    "Attributes": [
        {
            "Name" : "Emp",
            "Sortable" : false
        },
        {
            "Name" : "Sex",
            "Sortable" : true
        },
        {
            "Name" : "Race",
            "Sortable" : true
        },
        {
            "Name" : "Height",
            "Sortable" : true
        },
        {
            "Name" : "Weight",
            "Sortable" : true
        }
    ],
    "Values": [
        {
            "Emp" : "Emp-005",
            "Sex" : "Male",
            "Race" : "African",
            "Height" : "5.9",
            "Weight" : 67
        },
        {
            "Emp" : "Emp-002",
            "Sex" : "Male",
            "Race" : "Asian",
            "Height" : "5.9",
            "Weight" : 33
        },
        {
            "Emp" : "Emp-003",
            "Sex" : "Male",
            "Race" : "Asian",
            "Height" : "5.9",
            "Weight" : 45
        }
    ]
};
```

Plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/eEa6gvVDWkYPwiI20WNV?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you are having is that when iterating objects, the items of the object are retrieved in order of their keys, not in the order that you set the keys of the object. But in your case you can easily overcome this issue by doing this:

```
<table  class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr><th ng-repeat="instanceItem in instancesData.Attributes track by $index" >{{instanceItem.Name}}</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in instancesData.Values track by $index">
        <td ng-repeat="instanceItem in instancesData.Attributes track by $index">{{row[instanceItem.Name]}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/nKbZdKnicQU0MkExOY6H?p=preview)